# Creating SQL Table From CSV Information

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-2.7

I am trying to write a piece of Code in Python 2 that will read a CSV and create an SQL table accordingly however I am getting an error when trying to execute my SQL query. (I have left out the Connection to SQL as it has passwords etc in)

Could anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**ERROR-**

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server 
Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '1099'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")





m = re.search('.*\((.*)\)', _filename)

tablename = m.group(1)

extra_columns = [
    ]
valid_column_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() == '.csv':
        csv_filename = filename
        break

with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)

    headers = reader.next()

    for column in extra_columns:
        headers.append(column)

    nice_columns = []
    for column in headers:
        column = column.replace(' ', '')

        nice_column = ''
        for c in column:
            if c in valid_column_letters:
                nice_column += c

        nice_columns.append(nice_column)

    print 'Created table %s' % (tablename,)
    for column in nice_columns:
        print column

    command = 'CREATE TABLE ? (?);', '? VARCHAR(1000)'(tablename, for c in nice_columns)

    #command = 'CREATE TABLE %s (%s);' % (tablename, ','.join('%s VARCHAR(1000)' % (c,) for c in nice_columns))

    cursor.execute(command)

    cursor.commit()
```

I'd appreciate any feedback so I can get this fixed.
TY

Comment: To help you, we need either the first row data of your CSV file OR the data your list `nice_colums` is holding at the code line `command = ...`. Read [mcve].